# Pass window object across pages

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

Page A will open Page B, Page B will open Page C. 
Once Page C is loaded, close Page A.

In Page A, open up Page B :

```
var newWindowChild; 
$("#submitButton").click(function () {                                             newWindowChild = window.open('about:blank', 'TheNewWindow');
});
```

in Page C, how can i close Page A ? Is that possible to pass the newWindowChild across the pages from Page A to Page C, and do something like this?  :

```
window.close(newWindowChild);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Web Worker to achieve that. Below you can find a nice tutorial explaining how to use it.

http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-shared-web-workers-html5/

-Page C can postMessage "Page A Close"

-Page A can listen to the above Message and trigger window.close()